# Warning Message for "Self" in AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

Tags: angle

I am getting the following warning, and I am not sure how to fix it or if it is serious:
This is for the self statement that is enclosed in asterisks: sending ViewController warning message "const__strong to parameter of incompatible type AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

```
- (void) setupAVFoundationFaceDetection
{
    self.metadataOutput = [AVCaptureMetadataOutput new];
    if (! [self.session canAddOutput:self.metadataOutput])
    {
        NSLog (@"\nCould not add Face Detection...\n");
        return;
    }

    NSLog (@"\nIn Face Detection...\n");
    [self.metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:**self** queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.session addOutput:self.metadataOutput];

    if (! [self.metadataOutput.availableMetadataObjectTypes containsObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeFace] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Face Detection is not supported\n");
        //        [self teardownAVFFoundationFaceDetection];
        return;
    }

    self.metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeFace];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.metadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:(id)self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

somewhat late but might be helpful to people searching for the answer :)